# MySQL Subquery with datetime comparison from main query values

Tags: mysql, date, subquery

I am trying to do what seems like a simple query..  I have a query which works fine until I try to add a subquery to the select clause. I am trying to add a column by querying a second table with the dates I get from the first.  I don't know if a join might be better.  If you look at my first sample it returns every record in my second table instead of using the date range from the outer select statement.

```
SELECT `sales`.`date` as 'newdate', `sales`.`material`, 
`customer_logs`.`name`, `sales`.`billingqty` , 
(select count(*) from iis_logs where datetime > (select 
Date_add(date_format(newdate, "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"), interval - 1 day)) 
and datetime < date_format(newdate, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00' and url like 
CONCAT('%',material,'%') limit 1) as tr
FROM `sales`
JOIN `customer_logs` ON `customer_logs`.`customer_number` = 
`sales`.`soldtopt`
WHERE `date` >= '2017-09-01'
AND `date` <= '2017-09-30'
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

If I just type the string as a date in like this it returns within a second:

```
SELECT `sales`.`date` as 'newdate', `sales`.`material`, 
`customer_logs`.`name`, `sales`.`billingqty` , 
(select count(*) from iis_logs where datetime > '2017-09-01 00:00:00' 
and datetime < '2017-09-03 00:00:00' and url like 
CONCAT('%',material,'%') limit 1) as tr
FROM `sales`
JOIN `customer_logs` ON `customer_logs`.`customer_number` = 
`sales`.`soldtopt`
WHERE `date` >= '2017-09-01'
AND `date` <= '2017-09-30'
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

It is not taking the value of newdate I am trying to get in select statement, instead it is returning every row in iis_logs table...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a perfect candidate for a join. FWIW, mysql query optimizer typically does better on joins that subqueries anyway.

Comment: I have tried with a join also, whenever I use the result from the select instead of a literal date it does not work anymore.  Am I doing something wrong with using the result of the select as the date between comparison?

Comment: select date_format(`s`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:59') as 'end', 
    date_format(`s`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') as 'start', `s`.`material`, 
    `s`.`billingqty`, iis_logs.datetime
    from sales s
    left join iis_logs
    on iis_logs.datetime between date_format(`s`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d 
    00:00:00') and date_format(`s`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
    WHERE `date` >= '2017-06-05'
    AND `date` <= '2017-06-30'
    LIMIT 5;

Comment: I cancel it after about 5 minutes of processing, I am sure im doing something wrong but I cannot figure out how to make this work, if I replace the s.date field with literal text like '2017-09-05 00:00:00' it works in about 4ms...

Comment: Well, all 3 queries do something different for a start. I don't see any count or group by in the join query you posted. You might try adding iis_logs.datetime to the where or on clause as well. As always, EXPLAIN is your friend in these situations.

Comment: I am basically just trying to add a column to this query that counts iis_logs for the day listed in sales.date

Comment: select date(date_format(`s`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:59')) as 'end', date(date_format(`s`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')) as 'start', `s`.`material`, `s`.`billingqty`, count(iis_logs.datetime)
from sales s
join iis_logs
on iis_logs.datetime between 'start' and 'end'
where iis_logs.datetime < 'end'
and iis_logs.datetime > 'start'
and `date` >= '2017-06-05'
AND `date` <= '2017-06-06'
LIMIT 5;

Comment: That didnt do much either